# I am unable to install basemap in windows command prompt

Tags: python

I already downloaded the basemap tar.gz file and extracted using 7zip. I am trying to install the setup file that is currently in the Download folder into my python folder but I am unable to do so.

[image]

[image]

Here is the command I entered in the windows command prompt displayed in the image file:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Pentazoid>c:/python35/python setup.py install
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Pentazoid>c:/Users/python/python35 setup.install
'c:/Users/python/python35' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Can you add `python` to your `PATH` variable in Environment Variables and repeat the installation step ?

Comment: How would I add python to my path? I thought I did add python to my path?

Comment: I am not sure what Path I need to install the setup.py file for basemap in

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path) is the way you can add `PYTHONPATH` , once you do this, you can check if it's available by opening up `cmd` and running `python --version`. Then in the basemap folder run `python setup.py install`